# Finding $\lim_{n\to \infty}\;n\theta(n)$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, continuity

Let $f$ be a positive and continuous function in the interval $[0,1]$. It can be shown that there exists for every natural number $n$, a real number $\theta(n)\in [0,1]$ such that

$$\frac{1}{n} \int_0^1f(x)dx = \int_0^{\theta(n)} f(x)dx + \int_{1-\theta(n)}^1 f(x)dx$$

Find $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\;n\,\theta(n)$$

My attempt:

I tried to use IVT, mean value theorem on suitable functions (trial and error). But all are failing.

Additionally, I have got that RHS = $\int_0^{\theta(n)}(f(x) + f(1-x))dx$. I want to use this symmetry to some good use but ran out of ideas. Any help?

Comment: The integral version of the mean value theorem might help, $\int_0^{\theta(n)}f(x)dx = \theta(n)f(x_n)$ for some $x_n \in [0, \theta(n)]$.

Comment: So, can you solve it now?

Comment: For $f(x)=1$ it is easy to see that the limit is $1/2$. For $f(x)=x(1-x)$ the limit turns out to be $+\infty$ (If I did not do any stupid mistakes). So, maybe the answer is dependent on some property of the function?

Comment: I realize that my second example is not an example, since that function is just non-negative, and not positive. I suggest to add some small number to it, and see what happens...

Comment: @Michael, I could get such an above $x_n$ and $y_n$ ($y_n$ for 2nd integral term). I can re-write the equation as $f(x_n)$ + $f(y_n)$ = $\frac{1}{n}( \int_0^1 f(x) dx)/ \theta(n)$. As n $\to$ $\infty$, as LHS goes to zero, since f is a positive and cont function, each term in the RHS of original equation go to 0 individually which can happen only if $\theta(n)$ go to $0$. This means $x_n$ and $y_n$ go to 0 and 1 r.ly. Thus, $\frac{1}{n}$ ( $\int_0^1 f(x) dx)$/ $\theta(n)$ approaches $f(0)$ + $f(1)$ as $n \to \infty$ and answer is obtained from this by re-writing this. rigorous proof soon.

Comment: @user166305 : Your overall approach is good (I gave plus 1) but you may have a typo in your comment above since "as LHS goes to zero" did not make sense to me, since the LHS was $f(x_n)+f(y_n)$ which does not necessarily go to zero.  I think you meant that $\frac{\int_0^1f(x)dx}{n}$ goes to zero.

Comment: @Michael, yes you are right, sorry. I meant the LHS of the original equation of reference in my question. Sorry for not being precise. There was space constraint in comment.